# How do I specify which computer should receive Microsoft Teams calls?

Tags: microsoft-teams

***Background:***
I have Microsoft teams running a computer in the office and on my laptop at home.  Since most of my applications are on the office computer, when I work from home I do so using a remote desktop session into that computer.  The problem is that I have teams open on the work computer, but when I get a Teams Call it doesn't have the video or audio available on the laptop.  I would have thought I could just switch to the teams on the laptop and answer the call there, but the call seems to present in only one place.  Tried with a third computer as well and it still only presents the Teams call in one place.

***Question:***
How can I tell Microsoft Teams to present voice calls to all computers or to prefer one computer over another for voice calls?  The Teams on the office computers has it's settings such that it has no microphone and no camera. I also removed the Media permission from it in Teams.

***Workaround:***
My workaround now is when I get a voice call to exit teams on my desktop and ask them to call again, but this disrupts the workflow.

Comment: If you are logged into a device with a camera and microphone, why can't you just log out of the other device, that way you can receive calls.  I will be honest, I don't believe Teams supports multiple devices, even Skype wasn't very good with every single device ringing.  *Teams is relatively new product compared to Skype/Lync/Ect and I don't believe it supports the workflow you want*

Comment: Technically I can, it just doesn't make for an easy workflow.  I am on Teams all day long and need to work on things at the same time as chatting with coworkers.  Having a remote desktop window on one side of the screen just to have teams and only teams on the other side isn't effective.  You would think if it couldn't be determined which computer received the call that they all should be presented the call and whichever answered it received it.  Instead it only works for one and the wrong one.

Comment: They might have thought to do it, but until they write that code, it likely goes to the first device that is logged in.

Comment: @Ramhound I can try that.  I'll logout everywhere and then login first on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was requested in 2017 in the feature request
[Transfer active call between devices](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/19032928-transfer-active-call-between-devices?page=1&per_page=20).

Just recently, in  January 14, 2020, the Admin named Alex from
Teams Engineering, Microsoft Teams, gave this information:

> The team has begun working on this feature. We’ll update as we have more details to share.

I suggest to follow the above feature request for future updates.

Up until then, the only option seems to be to
[Transfer a call in Teams](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/transfer-a-call-in-teams-b7f40f14-e083-46b9-b739-68038c8f73a0),
which requires a different user name for the person to transfer the call to,
which means that you should juggle two user names while at work or at home.

Comment: That's a lot more complex of a feature than I was looking for, but thank you for the information as it would solve the problem.

Comment: It was helpful and I have up-voted it.